# Rampart ignores password callback handler while loading policy dynamically

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, rampart, wso2-esb

I'm trying to implement dynamic policy loading during Axis2 InFlow execution. One of the additional module that is put before 'Security' phase of the Axis2 flow is responsible to determine the policy that needs to be applied and load it as necessary. Here's few lines from the handler that load the policy.

```
...
RampartConfig rampartConfig = new RampartConfig();
...
 rampartConfig.setPwCbClass("com.example.security.callback.UsernamePasswordCallbackHandler");
...
Policy policy = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(policyElement);
policy.addAssertion(rampartConfig);
messageContext.getOptions().setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY, policy);
....
```

The policy looks like following.

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" xmlns:wsu=
    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
        <sp:SupportingTokens
                xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken=
                                          "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:HashPassword/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:UsernameToken>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SupportingTokens>
    </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

Right after the startup the policy is loaded successfully and reaches password callback handler. But if you try to complete a request one more time with any credentials you put into the request - it will go through instead of returning a fault.

This means that for the secong and further requests rampart ignores password callback handler some how.

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 ant it's quite annoying it doesn't work as per pure Axis2/Rampart documentation.

If anybody could help that would be great as I'm currently stuck with this problem.

Thanks,
Vladimir.